# What is the derech halimud of the Rogachover

Tags: talmud-gemara

I've always wanted to understand what is the derech halimud of the rogatchover. What is the difference between him and other contemporaries. I read that he learned with reb chaim brisker, 5 years his senior.
Also I heard the lubavitcher rebbes derech halimud is from the rogatchover.
Also do we have any sichas from the rogatchover. I learnt one said over in a sicha, but can't remember the source.

Comment: His sefer is the Tzofnas Paneach ... are you looking for sichos on Chasidus?

Comment: Rav Zevin has a beautiful article on the Rogatchover and his way of learning. It’s printed in Ishim veShitot.

Comment: I would recommend this article: https://hakirah.org/vol15schwartz.pdf

Comment: Joel k, do you have a link

Comment: Shalom k, Sichas in nigleh and nistar.